# Facilitation to deal with logs

Tags: logging

My program prints simple debug log to stdout: start/end points of called functions, values of important variables and other useful information.

I am curious if there is any tool which facilitates viewing the log - auto intention, syntax highlighting, more. Is there any formal notations for logging and tools and plug-ins to deal with logs
.

Answer (score 0):

which programming language are you using? 
in case you are using ruby, this could be a good choice:https://rocketjob.github.io/semantic_logger/rails.html

on the other hand, if you want to visualize the logs [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana) is a good choice

Comment: This is not what I am asking for... Language does not matter for my situation. I print log. I just want to read it in formatted view.